# Return to the beginning of the table

Tags: python

I have a table with numbers inside like this:

2,

3,

4,

When I read all the line of the table I would like to start to read the table again.
I'm writing in python and for the moment the only solution that I have is to do while loop which copies the table.

But this solution isn't very good.
Do you know how I can do this?

Including code from author's comment:

```
infile = open(filename, "r")
x = 1
while (x <= int(nb_time_read)):
    for line in infile.readlines():
        String.split((line),',')
        x = x+1

infile.close()
```

Comment: You need to show some of your code to get reasonable help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'table'? Where is this data coming from? How are you accessing it? Give us some sort of information.

Comment: The data are on a file, I open the file to put the data on a table.
In fact I don't to read the file again, just go to the top of the table and read it again.
Currently, I don't think my code is very useful because it doesn't work like I want
infile = open(filename, "r")
x = 1
while (x <= int(nb_time_read)):
 for line in infile.readlines():          
            String.split((line),',')
        x = x+1    
infile.close()

Comment: @tranen returns to begining of the file? `fileObject.seek()` function may lead you to the begining.

Comment: If your data isn't prohibitively large, store the parsed data in a list. You can then access it any way you please without reloading the file.

Comment: Instead of showing (unreadable) code on comment, include it on your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
infile = open(filename, "r")
table = []
for line in infile:
    table.append(line.split(",")
```

Now you can run over the rows in your table (`for row in table`) or directly access cells (`table[2][0]`) as many times as you like.

If your data is CSV, you should consider using the csv module to handle it properly.